# Permission problems when setting active host

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-machine

I'm setting active host and having Docker client point at it:

```
docker-machine env [instance name]
```

That gives me output:

`Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host. You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'`

when I try to regenerate the certs I get this from the debug log: `fork/exec /usr/bin/ssh: permission denied`

Changing permission settings for the directory didn't help. How can I troubleshoot it ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-not-available-when-creating-docker-machine-through-digitalocean

Problem was running Docker as a snap (Ubuntu's repo) instead of official build from Docker. As soon as I uninstalled the Docker snap and installed official build SSH problem has gone away.